# Linq query w/ sub query and max

Tags: c#, linq

How do I rewrite this SQL into a Linq query?

**Plain SQL**

```
SELECT *
FROM contracts
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT contractid, max(date) date 
        FROM contractlogs GROUP BY contractId) b 
    ON contracts.id = b.contractId
```

**Attempt at Linq**

```
from c in _db.Contracts
join sub in (from cl in _db.ContractLogs
             group cl by cl.contractId into g
             select new { contractId = g.contractId, changedate = g.Max(x => x.date)})
    on c.id equals sub.contractId 
select new { c, cl }
```

Goal of the query is to select all contracts w/ their newest update (first) (in contractLogs). I'm currently stumped on how the select would work. Ideally i'm trying to return an object with c & cl.

Comment: You posted some C# code.  What does this code do, and how is that different from what you wanted?

Comment: @MobyDisk sorry i'm trying to rewrite the SQL into Linq

Comment: Your LINQ query seems correct. What's the problem with it?

Comment: Couldn't you rewrite the original SQL to not have the subquery?  That makes the translation process easier.  Ex: SELECT *, max(contractlogs.date) FROM contracts INNER JOIN contractlogs ON contracts.id = contractlogs.contractId GROUP BY contractId

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek nope doesn't work, won't compile

Comment: Oh, I see where the problem is. Change `{ c, cl }` to `{ c, sub }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the most recent log by sorting them in descending order and taking the first one:

```
from c in _db.Contracts
let mostRecentContractLog = c.ContractLogs
                             .OrderByDescending(cl => cl.date)
                             .FirstOrDefault()
select new { c, mostRecentContractLog }
```

As you see, I assume you have a navigation  property `Contract.ContractLogs`. It's always strongly recommended to work with navigation properties in stead of manually coded joins.

Comment: Does this produce only the single most recently change? I think the OP is looking for the most recent for each group of rows grouped by the contractid. This seems a little too simple to do that...

Comment: The most recent log for each contract. The logs grouped by contractId are the logs belonging to one contract.

Comment: perfect thanks! thanks for the hint about navigation properties as well.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this it's often easier to write the query and subquery separately:

```
var subQuery =
    from cl in _db.ContractLogs
    group cl by cl.contractId into g
    select new { contractId = g.Key, date = g.Max(cl => cl.date) };

var query =
    from c in _db.Contracts
    join cl in subQuery on c.contractId equals cl.contractId
    select new { contract = c, cl.date };
```

Answer (score 0):

The most literal translation is going to involve you calling groupby on ContractLogs and then joining that into Contacts. I think the ordering of your operations in your LINQ attempt is a little off however I don't often use the query syntax so I'm not positive about that. Regardless, I think you'd prefer something like this;

```
_db.ContractLogs.GroupBy(x => x.contractId).Select(x => new { contractid = x.Key, changedate = x.Max(y => y.date) })
```

With that you can do the join into _db.Contracts but I think you could write it more simply with a where though that might be less optimized by the LINQ to SQL provider. Anyway, just completing the example with a join;

```
OldQuery.Join(_db.Contracts, cl => cl.contractid,
              c => c.contractid, (cl, c) => cl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from c in _db.Contracts
select new 
{ 
   c, 
   cl = _db.ContractLogs.Where(l => l.contractId == c.contractId).OrderByDescending(l => l.date).FirstOrDefault() 
}
```